# How to select the target audio output device for MediaElement?

Tags: .net, wpf, mediaelement

With .Net 4 MediaElement, is there a way to select the target audio output device? I know MediaElement plays audio to the Windows Default Sound Playback device. But I have an app that needs to work with systems with multiple sound cards and be able to direct the audio to specific sound cards. And changing the Windows Default Sound device programmatically is not an option.

I know DirectX 9.0c - DirectSound will let you do this, but DirectSound has been deprecated from DirectX since DX9 and who knows how much longer MS will keep it available.

Answer (score 3):

There's a open-source c# library available http://naudio.codeplex.com/.

And here's article for about audio devices http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.in/2011/05/naudio-audio-output-devices.html.

Comment: Thanks Neeraj. 
Naudio looks interesting but it doesn't use .Net MediaElement (as far as I can tell from their home page). My app is tied to using MediaElement for output.

Comment: @LTDan If your app is tied to MediaElement then i don't think if it's possible easily. You can try to make a class just like MediaElement but internally using NAudio.